# Do non-wrapping epoxy drawer slides still exist?

Tags: drawers

I need to replace the slides in a chest. The slides are epoxy slides manufactured by 'Waterloo'. The pieces that mount on the drawers do not wrap around the bottom of the drawer; they are screwed, flat, onto the sides, with the bottom of the slide about 1/4" above the bottom of the drawer side.

Polling around the internet and visiting Rockler have both come up empty. Is this an item that no longer exists, or am I simply looking for it under the wrong name somehow?

To clarify my goal: I was hoping to find an exact match so that I didn't have to recalculate the location of anything. Based on comments here, I concluded that this was not likely, so I bought a set of metal drawer slides and I sweated through the process of determining the alignment so that the drawer will go back where it came from. It only took two tries.

Comment: How much clearance do the existing slides take up on each side of the drawer? A question worth asking because you may be faced with replacing with some type of metal full extension drawer slides.

Comment: one half inch..

Comment: There should be any number of sturdy full extension metal drawer slides that fit in a half inch drawer side clearance.

Comment: OK, care to make that an answer?

Comment: How important to you is it that the slides be "epoxy-coated"? 
A very cursory websearch for "epoxy drawer slides" combined with various manufacturer names isn't finding anything but undermount slides, but there are plenty of traditional side-mount slides in a wide range of sizes and functionality if you're willing to accept chrome or darkened-metal appearance.